# How to get Hostname of each ip address in given input range

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

My question is how to get hostnames of all ip addresses which are betwwen given ip range. I know the function for getting hostnames from ip address but I just want to know how to get ip addresses from given range

Example:

- input is given in two edixboxes in first `'0.0.0.0'` and in second `'1.1.1.1'` so I want all ip addresses between this range ...

I tried my best but it is too complex. Is there any function or command to get ip addresses between given range?

```
function IPAddrToName(IPAddr: string): string;
var
  SockAddrIn: TSockAddrIn; 
  HostEnt: PHostEnt;
  WSAData: TWSAData;
begin
  WSAStartup($101, WSAData);
  SockAddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr(PChar(IPAddr));
  HostEnt := GetHostByAddr(@SockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_addr, 4, AF_INET);
  if HostEnt<>nil then
  begin
    Result := StrPas(Hostent^.h_name)
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := '';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := IPAddrToName(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `inet_addr` to convert the dotted text form of the IP address into an unsigned 32 bit integer. Do that for both addresses. And then loop from one to the other with a simple for loop.

```
var
  ip, ip1, ip2: Cardinal;
....
ip1 := ntohl(inet_addr(PChar(edit1.Text)));
ip2 := ntohl(inet_addr(PChar(edit2.Text)));
for ip := min(ip1,ip2) to max(ip1,ip2) do
  // use ip
```

I skipped any validation. You would not. Note also that `inet_addr` returns a value with network byte order. For the loop to work we must switch to host byte order.

This only really makes sense for ranges that span an entire subnet mask. For instance it makes sense to enumerate all addresses between 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.1.255. But it makes no sense at all to ask for all addresses between 1.0.0.0 and 1.1.1.1 as per the example in your question.

So I think you'll need to reconsider and think about iterating over all addresses in a network.

You also ask, in comments, how to convert from numeric form to dotted form. Use `inet_ntoa` for that.

```
var 
  addr: in_addr;
  dottedAddr: string;
....
addr.S_addr := htonl(ip);
dottedAddr := inet_ntoa(addr);
```

Comment: Thank you it is working,But it is giving cardinal values between given range,can you please tell me how to convert cardinal values to ip again.I am sorry .i am beginer

Comment: Use `inet_ntoa`. But you don't need to do that. Change `IPAddrToName` to receive ip address as `Cardinal` which you use directly instead of `inet_addr(PChar(IPAddr))`. Once you convert from string to numeric, stay working with numeric.

Comment: i am not getting you ,can you please update your code?

Comment: My aim is to display all ips between given ip range.No other calculations need to do

Comment: That's not what your question asks. You ask how to get all IP addresses in a range. No mention of displaying dotted form. Anyway, you can call `inet_ntoa` to convert from numeric to dotted, as I said.

Comment: Sir if i choose ip range from 1.0.0.0 to 1.1.1.1 then it is giving in output as 2.0.0.0,3.0.0.0 which are of other networks.So how to get only ips from same network Example: 1.0.0.0 to 1.1.1.1 which would include only ip addresses of network 1 like 1.0.0.0,1.1.0.0,1.2.0.0 upto 1.1.1.1

Comment: You also need to consider the subnet mask. It doesn't makes sense to go between 1.0.0.0 and 1.1.1.1.

Comment: thats just an example sir. i am asking in general by considering subnet mask how to get ips in given range

Comment: Oh, I guess byte order is the issue. Is the address returned in network byte order?

Comment: Yup, I forgot about byte order. Try now.

Comment: Very difficult to know what you are looking for here. I don't see what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

Generating IP addresses is not that complicated. Just convert range bounds to 4 byte integers and iterate between bounds. Pay special attention to bytes order so integers was correctly converted to IP addreses.